# Fancybox loads halfway down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am using the fancybox plugin for my web app. I am using it to display a simple tutorial for a first time user. When you first use my app you see the tutorial automatically. I use JQuery to trigger the link to open the modal once the page loads.

jQuery to trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tutorial').trigger('click');
});
```

My link that opens the fancybox modal:

```
<a id="tutorial" href="#profile-tutorial" class="fancybox-open"> Profile Tutorial </a>
```

Now, when the page loads it automatically pops up, but some reason it loads halfway down the page. But if I click the link directly, it loads in the middle just fine. I have no idea what could be causing this. What could it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the click on load should solve your problem:

```
$(window).load(function () { $('#tutorial').trigger('click'); });
```

Comment: Sry, because the ready event is triggered when the dom is ready. This doesnt mean that the whole page is builded completely. On load is triggered when the whole page is build up, including all images and js. Maybe google it for a better explanation ;)